# How to divide the following polynomial and factor it?

Tags: arithmetic, factoring

The question is 
 $$ (2x^3+3x^2-39x-20) / (x-4) $$

I divided the following and got this as the answer
$$ 2x^2+9x+3-8/(x-4))$$
I thought that this was the answer, but when i looked at the answer sheet the answer was this $$(x-4)(x+5)(2x+1)$$
I think the answer should've been factored but i don't know how to factor this 
 $$ (2x^3+3x^2-39x-20) / (x-4) $$
and also i have a general question about factoring these types of problems
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
which method would i choose, because i should be getting 3 answers and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The first part of your work seems to show you got a remainder of $-8$ which should have been zero.  You should check your work, and then your problem is how to factor the quotient (which is a simple quadratic polynomial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing $2x^3 +3x^2 -39x -20 $ by $(x-4)$ should give you $2x^2 +11x+5$

Then factorise $2x^2 +11x+5$ to get the remaining factors:

$$2x^2 +11x+5 = (2x + 1)(x+5)$$

For more on dividing polynomials, see the following [khan academy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/arithmetic-with-polynomials/long-division-of-polynomials/v/dividing-polynomials-1)

Comment: oh okay, and would you have any information regarding how to solve polynomials with 3 as the exponent like this $$2x^3+2x^2+x+3$$ (Like how to solve or factor the following types of problems)

Answer (score 3):

$4$ is a root of $3x^3+3x^2-39x-20$, hence it is divisible by $x-4$. To obtain the quotient, you can use *Horner's scheme*:
$$\begin{array}{rrcrcrr}
&2&&3&&-39&&-20\\
\hline
&&&8&&44&&20\\
&&\!\!\nearrow\!\!&&\!\!\nearrow\!\!\!\!&&\!\!\nearrow\!\!\!\!\\
{}\times 4&\color{red}{2}&&\color{red}{11}&&\color{red}{5}&&0
\end{array}$$
Hence $\;2x^3+3x^2-39x-20=(2x^2+11x+5)(x-4)$.

The quadratic polynomial has discriminant equal to $81$, hence its roots are $-5$  and $-\frac12$, so it factors as $(2x+1)(x+5)$ and 
$$\frac{2x^3+3x^2-39x-20}{x-4}=\frac{(2x+1)(x+5)(x-4)}{x-4}=(2x+1)(x+5)$$

Comment: Would you happen to know how to factor these type of polynomial?$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

Comment: You can factor if you have a root. If there is an obvious root (say an integer root, which you may guess with the *rational roots theorem*), it's easy. If not, you have *Cardano's method*, which can be lengthy, especially if you have a term in $x^2$.